# How to use google calendar api for JavaScript with npm install?? Or is it possible to use google calendar api for nodejs in browser in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, google-calendar-api

I want to use google calendar api as library in Next.js without using _document.tsx. In that case, I have come up with 2 ways which might be possible as below;

1. Use google calendar api for JavaScript with npm install
2. Use google calendar api for node.js in browser in Next.js

Regarding 1, there is seemingly no ways to `npm install xxx` in the official site [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md), but `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>` is said to use. This is not what I wanted because I use Next.js so I wanna use this library using npm install.

As for method 2, `npm install googleapi` is introduced on the official site [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client), but I'm still concerned that it may only work on the server side. Since I am creating a dashboard-like site, I want to call the API from the client side (browser) when users request their dashboard, so if I can only run it on the server side, it will be a problem for me!

Anyone can answer that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

This approach is viable. You mentioned not wanting to use `_document.tsx` which makes me think you're not sure where to place the `<script>` tag that imports 3rd-party JS or if that's even allowed in Next.js. It is — you would use Next.js' custom [`<Script>`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) component instead which can be used in other pages and components. You'd just have to port [this example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) over to Next.js/React.

**Method 2**

The `googleapis` (or `@googleapis/calendar`) package will only work on the server side, but you can still call/access them from the client side (browser) if you import them into API pages. For example, `pages/api/gcal.ts` would import `@googleapis/calendar` then `pages/index.tsx` would make a [client-side data request](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side) to `http://localhost:3000/api/gcal`.

So for your case, I think method 2 is what you'd want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and clear answers, they are very helpful. You are right, I didn't understand where to put the <script> tag, and while I somehow thought I should put it in _document.tsx, I didn't want to use it because I didn't really understand it.

Comment: From the answers, I felt that both Method 1 and Method 2 could be used. 

However, regarding method 2, can I use it for this use case? Because the `pages/api/gcal.ts` in Method 2 would be a publicly exposed API endpoint in my understanding, so I was concerned that users could intentionally or accidentally execute the file `pages/api/gcal.ts` as long as they knew the URL. (Please let me know if my knowledge is insufficient)

Comment: Also, from a performance perspective, does method 1 load the google api resources each time a request is made for the relevant page (e.g., a page compiling `pages/index.tsx`)? If so, would method 2 be faster than method 1? I thought. Well, it may not make that much difference ...

Comment: @HiroshiNishio With method 2 being publicly exposed, you'd of course have to validate incoming requests, e.g., accepted request methods, valid payloads (you could use something like [Ajv](https://ajv.js.org/)), rate-limiting, etc. As for performance, most modern browsers cache JS and Next.js bundles all the JS anyway so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Certainly, it seems possible to control the requests sent to the page `pages/api/gcal.ts` by setting conditions, such as the methods to be allowed and access limits.
But the truth is, I haven't used `pages/api/gcal.ts` yet, so considering that, I think I'll go ahead with method 1!

Answer (score 1):

In case people are still looking for a definitive working solution event after reading **@Mark G's** response above here is the way I implemented it.

Package used:

```
npm i googleapis --save
```

Step 1: Create a `googleService.js` file under the `/pages/api`

Step 2: initialized the google javascript object over here as this runs on server side this will work fine

```js
// Import the Google Calendar API
const { google } = require('googleapis')

export default function handler(req, res) {
  // Fetch Calendar Service Instance
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    res.status(200).json({
      googleApiInstance: google.calendar({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_G_API_KEY,
      }),
    })
  }
}
```

Step 3: Used this res object to set the Google API instance object in my service file using the `useEffect` hook on my main application landing page. As I didn't want to create multiple API handling in the `pages/api` way

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`api/googleService`).then((res) => {
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(data.message)
      }
      res.json().then((data) => {
        if (data?.googleApiInstance) {
          GoogleService.initService(data.googleApiInstance)
        }
      })
    })
  }, [])
```

Not the ideal way I would have loved to do this, but hope this helps for others.